# How to limit the amount of lines a user has using return?

Tags: ios, swift, textview

In this project, users have the ability to write a bio with a character limit of 150.  Is it also possible to limit the number of lines a user can have? For example when I press return on the keyboard, it creates a new line. And I can do that as many times as I like, can I change that?

Similar to how Instagram limits how long a bio (height wise) can be somehow while still having a character limit.

Heres the code for character limit

```swift
  // Give textView character limit of 150
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {



        if(textView.text.count > 150 && range.length == 0) {
            print("Opps hit 150")
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false

            return false
        }

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true

        return true
    }
```

**Update**

Based on the answer I received, here is the updated code

```swift
 var lineCounter = 0


 extension EditProfileController: UITextViewDelegate {

    // Give textView character limit of 150
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        // Prevent the user from creating to many new lines.


            if(text == "\n") {
                lineCounter += 1
                if lineCounter == 20 {
            }
            print("Stop sending user to next line")
                return false
            }



        if(textView.text.count > 150 && range.length == 0) {
            print("Opps hit 150")
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false

            return false
        }

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true

        return true
    }

}
```

So the good news is when I click return it doesn't create a new line. However is it possible to allow the return button to create 4 new lines before rerunning false?

Comment: var lineCounter = 0 should be outside of your delegate func.

Comment: Opps sorry the function is actually in an extension. I've updated the question. It won't me allow to store properties in the extension.

Comment: Add that variable into EditProfileController main block, otherwise, this code will not work.

Comment: Silly, didn't even think about something so simple. Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: Also, I updated my answer. If this works for you, please accept my answer. Happy coding.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate, you can take a class variable like LineCounter and inside your delegate method, you should use the below code. It will minimize the need of your requirement.

// Member variable

```
var lineCounter = 0
```

For example, you want, user can tap the Return button maximum 5 times but he can input 150 char.

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if(text == "\n") {
            lineCounter += 1
            if lineCounter >= 5 {

            return false
        }
        }

        if(textView.text.count > 150 && range.length == 0) {
            print("Opps hit 150")
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Line ```textView.resignFirstResponder()``` says "Will never be executed" not sure if there is a syntax error in there or not.

Comment: Did you make LineCounter Constant (let instead of var) or check your "if condition". If not, Check other delegate methods who is keeping the keyboard enable.

Comment: Okay, I fixed that issue, it was on my side. My next question is, how can I have the return button send a user to a new line maybe 4-5 times before stopping it like such?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the user can tap Return max 5 times but he can write 150 char. Then remove 'resignFirstResponder()', use like if(text == "\n") {
            lineCounter += 1
            if lineCounter >= 5 {
               return false
            }
        }

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the height of the textView based on their font size, and check in the UITextViewDelegate if that height was reached

```
func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool { 
    // check here
}
```